# Questions about @import of fonts in CSS

Tags: css, google-font-api

I am using the @import method as answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14676665/2749256) by @ModernDesigner to import a Google Font to my Magento theme.

My question is, how does font importing work? Will the browser sit waiting to download the font on every page load, or is this just going to be loaded once and then following pages will just use a cached version?

What happens if the google server is down and the font can't be loaded? Will it completely block my site or will the browser continue and use the best fit alternative font?

I'd also like to add that I removed the http: from the url as the same css file is used for the checkout pages and using http breaks the https security status. Is this ok?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

1. Fonts will be cached, so they are just loaded once.
2. In case Googles CDN server should ever be offline, the fallback fonts of your CSS are used. Your site won't be blocked.
3. Just use `://` instead of `https://` or `http://`

But keep in mind:
You are exposing every user who's visiting your site to Google. I know this might sound a bit paranoid, but I feel like more people should see this as a disadvantage and care about the requests of their sites. Especially in times where intelligence services have gone crazy.