# Google fonts not loading on Mobile

Tags: css, mobile, google-font-api

I am trying to use Google font Six Cap on my webpage http://iconablare.in/iconablareredesign

It is working perfectly on Desktop but it doesn't load on mobile with the full website but when i tried to make a new html file with just that font

http://iconablare.in/iconablareredesign/style.css it loads on both web and mobile perfectly can anyone help out  ?

I am using same code in both files .

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If it is feasible for you to try to include your google font link scripts in your header instead of importing it in your css like this :

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

instead of this:

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans+Condensed:300);
```

and try to see if that works,

Anyway if your header is not accessible or you insist on importing it in your css make sure that the @import lines of code to be the very first line file like this:

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Six+Caps);
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Marcellus+SC);
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans+Condensed:300);

img, object, embed, video {
    max-width: 100%;
}
/* IE 6 does not support max-width so default to width 100% */
.ie6 img {
    width:100%;
}
```

instead of this:

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* Simple fluid media
   Note: Fluid media requires that you remove the media's height and width attributes from the HTML
   http://www.alistapart.com/articles/fluid-images/ 
*/
img, object, embed, video {
    max-width: 100%;
}
/* IE 6 does not support max-width so default to width 100% */
.ie6 img {
    width:100%;
}


@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Six+Caps);
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Marcellus+SC);
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans+Condensed:300);
```

(Also discussed here: [How to import Google Web Font in CSS file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14676613/how-to-import-google-web-font-in-css-file))

Answer (score 1):

Make sure
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Font+Name">`
comes after
`<link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet">`.

Comment: This helped fix my problem when using iOS.  Thank you!