# Font Family not working

Tags: html, css, fonts, webfonts

I am using Google Fonts on an internal webpage but for some reason it is not catching.

I downloaded the `.woff2` files and have them hosted on my server.

I included the `@font-face` and here is how I wrote it:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Arizonia';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Arizonia'), local('Arizonia-Regular'), url(/lib/fonts/Arizonia/PwrsyFTYH2Wmsvpn0dx4s_esZW2xOQ-xsNqO47m55DA.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2212, U+2215, U+E0FF, U+EFFD, U+F000;
}

.arizonia {
    font-family: 'Arizonia';
}
```

Then later in the HTML document, I have tags as:

`<span class="arizonia">Some Text</span>` but the text shows up as Times New Roman (default for the browser...). It somehow is not loading the font.

I checked the file and it IS accessible - meaning the URL to the `.woff2` file is valid.

I am using Firefox 30.0

Any ideas what could be wrong?

Comment: Can you see the webfont loading in your Sources tab in Chrome Dev Tools?

Comment: Did you try other browsers?

Comment: It doesn't look like it is importing. I used the Mozilla Firefox debugger and it shows all the various files loading. When I click on "Fonts", it doesn't show anything loading. I guess that isolates the problem. Any idea how to debug that?

Comment: NOTE: under the styles section of the debugger, this section of css (that declares the font-face) does load. So it loads the `style` statement, but somehow is still not importing the `.woff` file...

Comment: Maybe it is the woff2 compatibility? According to [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#search=woff2) it is compatible from Firefox 39+

Comment: Thanks @Alvaro - let me try `.woff`, not `.woff2`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to check it with other browser but it looks like it could be the **woff2 compatibility with Firefox 30**. According to [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#search=woff2) it is compatible from version 39 of Firefox. Include woff also. So something like this:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Arizonia';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Arizonia'), local('Arizonia-Regular'), url(/lib/fonts/Arizonia/PwrsyFTYH2Wmsvpn0dx4s_esZW2xOQ-xsNqO47m55DA.woff2) format('woff2'), url(/lib/fonts/Arizonia/PwrsyFTYH2Wmsvpn0dx4s_esZW2xOQ-xsNqO47m55DA.woff) format('woff');
  unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2212, U+2215, U+E0FF, U+EFFD, U+F000;
}

.arizonia {
    font-family: 'Arizonia';
}
```

Comment: I found a website where you can easily download the various versions of the Google API fonts, which is http://www.localfont.com/. I searched "Arizonia" and it had a simple `.zip` file to download and implemented perfectly. The problem was that I needed a fallback of a `.woff` file. Tku!

Comment: @WalkerFarrow As of July 5 2020, localfont.com is no longer working. Can you recommend a similar site?

Answer (score 1):

**Change the span to divs it should work:** 
**Internet Explorer 8 and earlier, do not support the @font-face rule with the WOFF format (only support for EOT format)

Check here for more info on how to implement: [How to import Google Web Font in CSS file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14676613/how-to-import-google-web-font-in-css-file)

EDIT** 
Check here for working example of what I am speaking of: https://embed.plnkr.co/qfEhb9LCEjh2PHqLlFF5/