# cfhtmltopdf not working with googleapis fonts

Tags: pdf, coldfusion

Why the cfhtmltopdf does not display the googleapis font?

```
<cfhtmltopdf encryption = "AES_128">
<html>
<head>
    <!--Add GoogleFonts-->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Aguafina+Script|Alex+Brush|Bilbo|Condiment|Great+Vibes|Herr+Von+Muellerhoff|Kristi|Meddon|Monsieur+La+Doulaise|Norican|Nothing+You+Could+Do|Parisienne|Permanent+Marker|Sacramento|Yellowtail" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>

        <p id="displaySignature" style="font-family: Meddon, cursive; font-size: 30px;">Test</p>

</body>

</html>
</cfhtmltopdf>
```

It ignores the font style.

Comment: It might be a timing issue. Google web fonts need to load before they can be used, and my guess is that cfhtmltopdf is not going to wait until they load, or maybe it doesn’t load external fonts.

Comment: I think it doesn't load external fonts. Do you know any way to display it in a pdf using ColdFusion?

Comment: Checkout the answer below... maybe that will work. Seems like you should be able to use external fonts, but you might need to use something else besides cfhtmltopdf. It also might depend on the version of ACF/Lucee you're using. Ortus just came out with a PDF generator for Lucee https://www.ortussolutions.com/products/ortuspdf

Comment: I just tested the initial HTML sample w/GoogleFonts using WKHTMLTOPDF.exe (which I use instead of CFPDF & CFHTMLTOPDF) and it generated a perfect PDF without having to jump through any hoops (adding a JS delay) or even hosting the HTML file on a traditional web server. SYNTAX: `wkhtmltopdf.exe test.htm test.pdf`

Comment: Do I need to install WKHTMLTOPDF in my server?

Comment: Maybe not helpful but: Works on my machine. I'm on CF 11, copied your code to an empty .CFM page, added CFOUTPUT tags, opened the page in a browser and got some fancy looking `Test`. Does your server generating the pdf have access to the internet? Can it reach google?You can download the font file from https://github.com/google/fonts/tree/8143a3e2d9f7656bc7e551f96d6294d47882d907/ofl/meddon

Comment: I think the server has access to the internet because without the cfdocument it displays the fancy Test string. It is the same server

Answer (score 1):

You can goto the ColdFusion administrator -> Server Settings -> Font Management and import the fonts that are required by you and try.

Comment: Can you add screen shots of what needs to be changed and it working?

Answer (score 0):

If you look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14676613/how-to-import-google-web-font-in-css-file), using

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans');
```

will import the contents of the CSS file into your HTML. Using `@import` will actually "defer the loading of the included resource until the file is fetched", which may be exactly what you need.

Comment: Thanks, but still not working. I think cfhtmltopdf does not support external fonts