# Import Google Fonts with scss: MIME-Type Conflict

Tags: css, angular, sass, fonts, google-fonts

I'm building an Angular app and I am using scss for styling and want to import google fonts.

I have a `fonts.scss` where everything related to fonts is saved. I import Google Fonts like this:

**fonts.scss**

```
 @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@300;400;700&display=swap');
 @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Raleway:wght@300;500;700&display=swap');
```

Because there are different files, I need to import to different components, I have a file called `imports.scss` that contains the fonts and more like color variables.

**imports.scss**

```
@import 'src/styles/imports/fonts';
@import 'src/styles/imports/colors';
```

Now, my **ng components** can use the fonts and variables with an import:

```
@import 'src/styles/imports';
```

Even though the variables and fonts are working, I am getting the following error in Google Chrome:

```
platform-browser.js:789 GET https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@300;400[_ngcontent-dsi-c57];700&display=swap net::ERR_ABORTED 400
```

and in **Firefox** I am getting this error:

```
The resource from "(link to google fonts)" was blocked due to MIME type mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff).
```

Is there a way to solve this problem?

Comment: Maybe you can find some hints here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14676613/how-to-import-google-web-font-in-css-file

Answer (score 0):

Google API font endpoints always return a stylesheet if there is no error, else they return a html error page.

This got me puzzled because I had a similar issue in which this html code (quite similar to your scss code)

```html
<link
  rel="stylesheet"
  href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Code"
/>
```

only logged this in the console

> The resource from “https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Code” was blocked due to MIME type (“text/html”) mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff).

The hard part to understand was that my browser requested a stylesheet (`Content-Type: text/css`) but Google responded with an html error page (`Content-Type: text/html`). Also, Google servers are configured with a [`nosniff` header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Content-Type-Options#nosniff) that basically *doesn't even send the error page back* if there is a mismatch between the requested content type and the to-be-responded response type.

Sadly it was this error page that gave away the source of the bug (I opened the stylesheet URL in another window):

[image: google error page]

I did a typo, it's *source code **pro***, not *source code*, so this

```html
<link
  rel="stylesheet"
  href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Code+Pro"
/>
```

worked as expected. I'm suspecting something similar on your end.