# <h1> font shows up on desktop and inspect under responsive but is a different font on mobile?

Tags: css, fonts, header

[image]Website is bluegrassdoodle.com and you can see the

```
<div id="logo">
     <h1><a href="index.html">Bluegrass Doodles</a>
     </h1>
</div>
```

The font-family has been added to , #logo, .logo as font-family:'Playlist Script';

Again, it works fine and you can see it on PC/Desktop but doesn't translate over on mobile.

*updated - checkout the photo* It shows responsive design on the actual site, pc look and I mirrored my iPhone screen to show the difference. Also, when I "go live" on VSCode, on the 127.0.0.1:port screen, it shows on mobile design the actual font that I'm wanting and not the block code showing on my phone.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use bootstrap latest CDN and code like this

```
<h1 class="h1"><a href="index.html">Bluegrass Doodles</a></h1>
```

Comment: I was on 4.1.3 and updatedc to 4.3.1 and no change to the font

Answer (score 0):

You can use `font-family:Playlist Script !important;` in your css file it will override the default value of font-family.

Comment: This changed from whatever cursive font was on there to some normal block font on mobile only. I do have some imported fonts on googleapis, is that overriding anything? This particular font I'm using can't be found on google. I had to download it, unzip and install on my PC.

Answer (score 0):

Reason for fonts showing up in your desktop only bcos you have the fonts installed locally in your hard disk. Either you have to upload the font into your server and import the font in your CSS file or if the font available in google fonts you can import them directly.

Check there urls, hope this helps

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/using-font-face/

[How to import Google Web Font in CSS file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14676613/how-to-import-google-web-font-in-css-file)

you may have to include this in your main.css

```
@font-face {
font-family: Playlist Script;
src: url(PlaylistScript.otf);
}
```

Comment: I figured that was the issue is the import. Not really sure how to import being it's not a google font. I added a photo of my links in my header

Comment: I would see you have referred the font "Playlist Script" in main.css but you haven't imported them. – Selvam Elumalai yesterday   Delete