# "Refused to apply style from because its MIME type "('font/woff2')" is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled"

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to use the font Product Sans in my website, and when I use

```
@import url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/productsans/v12/pxidypQkot1TnFhsFMOfGShVEueIaEx8qw.woff2);
```

It logs this error in the console:

> Refused to apply style from
> 'https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/productsans/v12/pxidypQkot1TnFhsFMOfGShVEueIaEx8qw.woff2'
> because its MIME type ('font/woff2') is not a supported stylesheet
> MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.

However, the font is still actually applied to all the texts, so what's the problem?

Comment: Hi, did you manage to get this through ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/productsans/v12/pxidypQkot1TnFhsFMOfGShVEueIaEx8qw.woff2` is a font, and you are trying to import it like it is a CSS file.

Or, reworded...
`@import` imports stylesheets and
`https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/productsans/v12/pxidypQkot1TnFhsFMOfGShVEueIaEx8qw.woff2` is not a stylesheet.

Please see: [How to import Google Web Font in CSS file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14676613/how-to-import-google-web-font-in-css-file) on how to import a font from google.

Comment: When I use @font-face, the font doesn't apply!
```@font-face { 
  font-family: "Product Sans";
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/productsans/v12/pxidypQkot1TnFhsFMOfGShVEueIaEx8qw.woff2);
}```