# how to get the .woof file from the google fonts

Tags: css, font-face, webfonts, google-font-api

As I understand the best way to include google fonts on a website is to use the `@font-face` and specify the location of the .woof file in the URL.

According to my understanding from reading the thread here [Including Google Web Fonts link or import?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12316501/including-google-web-fonts-link-or-import) using `@import` seems to be bad. And its difficult for me to import the font by specifying it as a `<link>` based on the layout that I have setup.

With all this into consideration I found that using this method seems best. eg.

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 300;
  src: local('Open Sans Light'), local('OpenSans-Light'), url(//themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/opensans/v8/DXI1ORHCpsQm3Vp6mXoaTaRDOzjiPcYnFooOUGCOsRk.woff) format('woff');
}
```

But when I select the required fonts https://www.google.com/fonts it doesn't show me the .woof file location, how can do I found this ?

Comment: Google looks at the User-Agent string from the request to css style and gives it specific for the browser defined by that UA. And links to `.woff`, `.woff2`, `.eot`, `.svg` are available inside of those styles.