# Google Fonts in <head> or in CSS with @import?

Tags: html, css, fonts, google-font-api

(I'm sorta new here so if this isn't the place to ask it, please tell me)

Normally I add `<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300italic,400,400italic,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>` into the `<head>` of my page. With several pages, there is always a chance for inconsistency/error plus updating every page can be a headache.

Can I instead just use `@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans);` at the first line of my main CSS file?

Advantage to this is updating one CSS file rather than updating every single page where it's in the `<head>`. But I've read some answers that say there may be a resource loading problem...but that discussion was 3 years ago. Can't find a current answer addressing this.

EDIT
To avoid SO from thinking this is duplicate, I am asking which is better method for 2015. I am not asking how to add Google fonts to a site under either method.

Comment: Yes, if you include the `@import` in your CSS file, the font will be accessible from any page using that CSS file.

Comment: yes you can, here is a post for you to reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14676613/how-to-import-google-web-font-in-css-file

Comment: So there won't be any resource loading issues? Can't find a recent answer - everything seems to be from 2 to 3 years ago when people said there was. Like this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12316501/including-google-web-fonts-link-or-import/12380004#12380004

Comment: you can bundle your css so there's only one request: http://love2dev.com/#!article/Using-GruntJS-to-Bundle-and-Minify-JavaScript-and-CSS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use an `@import` rule in CSS, browser can't dowload the referred script in parallel, simply because the carrying script has to be parsed before doing any downloads!

**Example #1**

`style1.css` and `style2.css` are loaded using the `<link>` tag:

[image: Example #1]

**Example #2**

`style1.css` is loaded using the `<link>` tag and `style2.css` is loaded using `@import` rule:

[image: Example #2]

To enable parallel downloading, use the `<link>` html tag instead.

Alternatively, you can inline CSS without using `@import` rule at all; stylesheet preprocessors can help you with that (e.g. Sass). You can try Node.js task runners ([gulp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp), [grunt](http://gruntjs.com/)) to automate such tasks.

Comment: Again - that question/answer was 3 years ago. Still an issue nowadays?

Comment: @chris, I've updated the answer, I hope it shows that this is still relevant :).

Comment: Thank you for going the extra mile and providing great info - appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Import in css is all right, there were issues several years ago in software like IE6 (only one file was loaded for multiple imports), but as you mentioned this is prehistoric, anyway, if you want to do this really good consider using some loader, like mentioned [here](http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/font-events.html), yet, import is all right as long as your webpage will be accesed online.