# Does a visitor to my webpage need to install the fonts?

Tags: html, css, font-face, webfonts

If I created a webpage with a custom font and used it, would the visitor have to install that font, or would it be embedded (so the visitor doesn't need to install anything)?

Comment: It depends on how you used the font, if you used something like TypeKit or google fonts, then the user doesn't need to install anything, if you are just referencing a custom font in your css then it will use the fallback fonts if the user does not have the fonts.

Comment: No, users do not **install** any fonts from visiting a web page. The question is too broad and off-topic, you can google "how web font works" or so, there is a great article by CSS-Tricks, you'll learn a lot from there I think - https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/using-font-face/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you used a custom font, you have to import it because if a visitor doesn't have a font in their OS it will be replaced with one of the default fonts

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14676613/how-to-import-google-web-font-in-css-file) is some information of how to import fonts to your web page

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12316501/including-google-web-fonts-link-or-import) you can find a little information about using google web fonts

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the visitor would have to install a custom font.

```
@font-face { font-family: Crazyfont; src: url('Crazyfont-Roman.otf'); }
```

Then you would reference it in the HTML like any other font.

```
h1 { font-family: Crazyfont, sans-serif; }
```

Comment: What if I embedded it into the website? Like the .otf file was in the same folder as index.html?

Comment: You just need to put the font the same folder as the HTML file and you're good.  Put Crazy_roman.otf in that folder.

Comment: So no need to download the font? Thanks!