# Custom google font (poppins) in Tailwind CSS?

Tags: import, fonts, tailwind-css, google-fonts

I want to use the Google font called poppins and this is the url of the font `https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@300&display=swap`. Does anyone know hot to do this?

Answer (score 15):

There are three steps to getting a custom font into a tailwindcss project.

1. Getting the font into the project
2. Configuring tailwindcss to use the font.
3. Using custom font-family

---

#### 1. [Getting the font into the project (Reply by: Adam Wathan)](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/discuss/issues/177#issuecomment-423755943)

Tailwind doesn't do anything special to auto-import fonts or anything, so you need to import them the same way you would in a regular project, either by adding the Google stylesheet reference to the top of your HTML like this:

```html
    <!-- index.html or similar -->
    <head>
      ...
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
```

...or by importing your fonts with @font-face declarations at the beginning of your CSS file:

```css
/* Example file: styles.css */

/* poppins-regular - latin */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Poppins';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url('../fonts/poppins-v15-latin-regular.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
  src: local(''),
       url('../fonts/poppins-v15-latin-regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
       url('../fonts/poppins-v15-latin-regular.woff2') format('woff2'), /* Super Modern Browsers */
       url('../fonts/poppins-v15-latin-regular.woff') format('woff'), /* Modern Browsers */
       url('../fonts/poppins-v15-latin-regular.ttf') format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
       url('../fonts/poppins-v15-latin-regular.svg#Poppins') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
}
```

[Which way? According to this SO answer: mostly prefer link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12380004/1511504)

#### 2. [Configuring tailwindcss to use the font - tailwind docs](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/font-family)

#### Customizing Font Families

By default, Tailwind provides three font family utilities: a cross-browser sans-serif stack, a cross-browser serif stack, and a cross-browser monospaced stack. You can change, add, or remove these by editing the theme.fontFamily section of your Tailwind config.

```js
      // tailwind.config.js
      module.exports = {
        theme: {
          fontFamily: {
           // Note: This is @notapatch and not the docs
           //       I think what it is trying to say is that if you define
           //       a custom font here you are also removing the default
           //       font families sans, serif and mono.
           //
           - 'sans': ['ui-sans-serif', 'system-ui', ...],
           - 'serif': ['ui-serif', 'Georgia', ...],
           - 'mono': ['ui-monospace', 'SFMono-Regular', ...],
           + 'display': ['Poppins', ...],
           + 'body': ['"Open Sans"', ...],
          }
        }
      }
```

// Docs end:

#### Customizing font-family with extend

The font-family docs don't cover this, but I've seen examples of extending the font-family instead of removing the default fonts sans serif and mono ... [this is from a github issue by simonswiss](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/discussions/2060#discussioncomment-190937)

```js
    // tailwind.config.js
    const defaultTheme = require('tailwindcss/defaultTheme')
    
    module.exports = {
      theme: {
    +    extend: {
          fontFamily: {
            sans: ['Poppins', ...defaultTheme.fontFamily.sans]
          }
    +    }
      }
    }
```

... will add Poppins to the font-sans stack, and preserve the other font families like font-mono, font-serif etc.

#### 3. Using custom Font-Family

Using a custom font-family is a matter of adding "font" to the fontFamily name. In our case, `font-display` and `font-sans`.

```html
    <h1 class="font-display">Example display font</h1>
    
    <p class="font-sans">Example text in body</p>
```

Note: Changed font to Poppins throughout answer to give consistency across text.

Answer (score 10):

If you want to directly import and use it from Google fonts,
Then add the `<link>` in your `<head>` section of your `index.html` file.

Then in your `tailwind.config.js` file

```
module.exports = {
  theme: {
     extend: {
        fontFamily: {
           'poppins': ['Poppins'],
        }
     }
  }
}
```

By defining your own font within `extend` will preserve the default theme fonts and add/extend your own font.

Now, you can use your font with the class `font-poppins` along with `font-sans` etc
You can add fallback font by adding it to the `poppins` array in the theme extension.

For more, please refer to the below links,
https://tailwindcss.com/docs/theme

https://tailwindcss.com/docs/font-family#customizing

Answer (score 6):

## 1. Import font

You can use `@import...` directive from the Google Font website to import web fonts in your `global.css` file. Be sure to put the directive at the beginning or it is invalid

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins&display=swap');
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

## 2. Use the font

As has mentioned by the other anwsers, you can configure the `tailwind.config.js` to generate a reusable utilities in your project. Besides, you can also use square bracket notation to generate a class on the fly. Just add `font-['Poppins']` to class properties.

Here is tailwind playground example:
https://play.tailwindcss.com/xZpx31j8W0

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I did

In your main scss file

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins&display=swap');
```

then in tailwind config....

```
theme: {
        extend: {
            fontFamily: {
                sans: ['Poppins', ...defaultTheme.fontFamily.sans],
            },
```

Answer (score 1):

I have this configuration in a `.css` file

```css
@font-face {
  font-display: swap;
  font-family: 'Nunito';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Nunito Regular'), local('Nunito-Regular'),
    url('~assets/fonts/Nunito-400-cyrillic-ext1.woff2') format('woff2');
}
```

And this in my `tailwind.config.js` file

```js
fontFamily: {
  // https://tailwindcss.com/docs/font-family#customizing
  sans: [
    'Nunito'
  ],
},
```

Thus I can use it in my markup with

```html
<p class="font-sans">
  I'm a sans-serif paragraph.
</p>
```

So yeah, my font is local but maybe my configuration can give you some insight on how to setup it on your side too.

Then, you could font-face's `url` key to set in the google fonts url as shown here: https://css-tricks.com/dont-just-copy-the-font-face-out-of-google-fonts-urls/

Answer (score 1):

I have done it this way for vite + react + tailwind CSS + shadcn/ui.

In my index.css file, I simply add this

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@200;300;400;500;600;700;800;900&display=swap');
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

@layer base {
  html {
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  }
}
```

My tailwind CSS config was not picking the font-family 'Poppins' and I want to use it everywhere (default)

Comment: The best answer IMO!

Answer (score 0):

I have tried and this was the method that worked for me

**Configure Tailwind for Poppins:**
Open your tailwind.config.js file and extend the fontFamily section to include Poppins

```
theme: {
 extend: {
    fontFamily: {
     poppins: ['Poppins', 'sans-serif'],
   },
  },
 },
}
```

**Use Poppins in HTML:**
Now, you can use the Poppins font in your HTML directly with Tailwind CSS classes:

`<div class="font-poppins">This text uses the Poppins font.</div>`

Make sure to rebuild your stylesheets after making changes to the tailwind.config.js file:

```
npx tailwindcss-cli -i src/input.css -o ./build/output.css
```