# How to efficiently load google fonts in Nuxt

Tags: css, vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js, google-fonts

I am using this google font `font-family: 'Saira Semi Condensed', sans-serif;`

Link: https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Saira+Semi+Condensed

I am working in on a NuxtJS project. I have to use this font in two different components but with different font-weight. I have imported all the google fonts links in `Layout.vue`.

For component A the `font-weight` is `600` & for component B the `font-weight` is `800`. So I thought giving different font-weights in the respective component will work. But it is not working. The only basic font has applied i.e.  `Saira Semi Condensed, sans-serif;` but the font-weight values are not reflected. To resolve this problem I need import two google font links with the same fonts but different font-weight in `Layout.vue` which makes it redundant.

For font-weight: 600

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Saira+Semi+Condensed:wght@600&display=swap%27);
```

For font-weight: 800

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Saira+Semi+Condensed:wght@800&display=swap%27);
```

I think my way of importing two links for the same fonts is not look good. Can you guys please help me to solve this issue?
Thank you in advanced.

**Code**:

Layout.vue

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <Nuxt />
  </div>
</template>

<style>
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nunito&display=swap');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Saira+Semi+Condensed:wght@600&display=swap');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Saira+Semi+Condensed:wght@800&display=swap');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@700&display=swap');

html {
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI',
    Roboto, 'Helvetica Neue', Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  word-spacing: 1px;
  -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
</style>
```

index.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <Navbar />
    <ComponentA />
    <ComponentB />
    <Footer />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Navbar from '../components/Navbar.vue'
import Clock from '../components/ComponentA.vue'
import Days from '../components/ComponentB.vue'
import Footer from '../components/Footer.vue'
export default {
  components: {
    Navbar,
    ComponentA,
    ComponentB,
    Footer,
  },
}
</script>
```

ComponentA.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>I am component A</h1>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'ComponentA',
}
</script>

<style scoped>
footer {
    color: blue;
    font-family: 'Saira Semi Condensed', sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: center;
 }
</style>
```

ComponentB.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>I am component B</h1>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'ComponentB',
}
</script>

<style scoped>
footer {
    color: red;
    font-family: 'Saira Semi Condensed', sans-serif;
    font-size: 24px;
    text-align: center;
 }
</style>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're loading your fonts from a CDN, which is not the recommended way of doing things.

Here is a quote from this [awesome performance checklist 2021](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2021/01/front-end-performance-2021-free-pdf-checklist/) written by Vitaly Friedman

> Now, many of us might be using a CDN or a third-party host to load web fonts from. In general, it’s always better to self-host all your static assets if you can, so consider using google-webfonts-helper, a hassle-free way to self-host Google Fonts. And if it’s not possible, you can perhaps proxy the Google Font files through the page origin.

Looking at this, I do recommend the usage of [`@nuxtjs/google-fonts`](https://github.com/nuxt-community/google-fonts-module), this is a cool Nuxt module.

I've actually asked if my configuration of the module was okay, here is the github issue: https://github.com/nuxt-community/google-fonts-module/issues/26

And here, a usage example in `nuxt.config.js`

```js
export default {
  buildModules: [
    [
      '@nuxtjs/google-fonts',
      {
        families: {
          Mali: {
            wght: [400, 600, 700],
          },
        },
        subsets: ['latin'],
        display: 'swap',
        prefetch: false,
        preconnect: false,
        preload: false,
        download: true,
        base64: false,
      },
    ],
  ]
}
```

And don't forget to also handle the **[@font-face](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66712645/8816585) CSS side** of course!

---

PS: in case you have some issues of [specific weights not being downloaded](https://github.com/nuxt-community/google-fonts-module/issues/101), you can use either [`overwriting: true`](https://github.com/nuxt-community/google-fonts-module/issues/101#issuecomment-1224875825) in your module configuration or bump the package version to [v3.0.0-1](https://github.com/nuxt-community/google-fonts-module/releases/tag/v3.0.0-1).

Comment: I am not getting your answer. Can you please give some good explanation or any blog or example?

Comment: @rakshit I'm not sure what to tell more here. I gave a configuration to load properly the Google font named `Mali` with an on-build Nuxt.js module. You can then use it anywhere you need. And the module also allows you to set specific weights. What would you need here?

Comment: You can then use it in your components with some CSS and set the weight with `font-weight: 700` or alike.

Comment: It is showing me like this.
`Error: Cannot find module '@nuxtjs/google-fonts'`

Comment: I don't understand, why did you set preload to false and base64 to false, doesn't it means that our font will NOT have to be loaded fully by the time your HTML/CSSOM is parsed and displayed?

Comment: @gazoon007 this is a `buildModules` and I don't want to download anything at runtime. So, it will only get the fonts once, and it will be available straight when the page will be rendered, no need for any preload or anything because the fonts will already be local.

Comment: But by this configuration, I have a problem with my project. So whenever the page has server-side routing or just reload the page during low connection, the font is always displayed the generic font (like monospace) and then later changes suddenly to google fonts, I don't know how by this configuration to make my font will have to be loaded fully before the HTML is rendered

Comment: @gazoon007 this is how a font works in CSS AFAIK. You can put a font that looks like that while loading tho.

Comment: @gazoon007 for me `base64: true` do the trick. I'm also using SSR and get my page with fully loaded fonts