# How to host google fonts locally in Nuxt

Tags: vuejs2, fonts, nuxt.js, google-fonts

I'm working with **vue 2.6** and **nuxt 2.14**.

I'm working on improving my website performance.

For this purpose I downloaded google fonts and passed `.woff2` files to `@font-face()` in `nuxt.config.js`.

But when I inspected in network, it is still getting fonts data from the Google servers.

I couldn't find any `https` request for `google fonts` in my project but request url was there in `.nuxt/index.js` build file.

`.nuxt/index.js`

```json
{
  "rel": "stylesheet",
  "type": "text\u002Fcss",
  "href": "https:\u002F\u002Ffonts.googleapis.com\u002Fcss family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900&display=swap"
}
```

I searched in project to figure out the source of this request.

[image]

I couldn't find any except this `.nuxt/index.js`

I even removed all the fonts but somehow it still was again getting `fonts` from `google server`.

And there's no trace of `fonts.gstatic.com` in my complete project including `.nuxt` build files.

[image]

Here's what I have done so far.

`nuxt.config.js`

```js
links: [{
  rel: 'stylesheet',
  href: '/fonts/roboto/fonts.css'
}]
```

`Some of the fonts`

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-display: swap;
  src: local('Roboto'), url(./KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmSU5fCRc4EsA.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0460-052F, U+1C80-1C88, U+20B4, U+2DE0-2DFF, U+A640-A69F, U+FE2E-FE2F;
}
/* cyrillic */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-display: swap;
  src: local('Roboto'), url(./KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmSU5fABc4EsA.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0400-045F, U+0490-0491, U+04B0-04B1, U+2116;
}
/* greek-ext */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-display: swap;
  src: local('Roboto'), url(./KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmSU5fCBc4EsA.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+1F00-1FFF;
}
```

here I've downloaded all the fonts.

[image]

I want to host fonts locally not from google server.

What I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this question was asked not so long ago. Here is my solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68166329/8816585

Give it a try, this is using `@nuxtjs/google-fonts` for some simple local fonts fetching during build time and works pretty well!