# nuxtjs/google-fonts Nunito font-weight not working on server

Tags: css, vue.js, fonts, nuxt.js, google-fonts

I am using nuxtjs/google-fonts package and the font-weight is working fine locally but once deployed to the server the font-weight is not being applied. How can I solve this problem?

here is my nuxt.config.js setup for google fonts

```
 googleFonts: {
families: {
  Nunito: {
    wght: [800, 900],
  },
},
```

},

I want the effect on my slider h2 element and here is the style for the h2

```
 h2 {
 font-family: "Nunito-sans", sans-serif;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 100;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 900;
}
```

Comment: Did you tried that one? https://stackoverflow.com/a/68166329/8816585