# How to configure TailwindCSS in Nuxt3?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, tailwind-css, nuxtjs3

I'm trying to set the default font `Proxima Nova` from TailwindCSS in my Nuxt3 project but am unfamiliar with the file structure. I've installed the `tailwindcss module`:

```
npm i -D @nuxtjs/tailwindcss
```

and added the module to `nuxt.config.ts`:

```
modules: [
    '@nuxtjs/tailwindcss'
],
```

but how do I change the `font-family`? There is a `nuxt` folder with `tailwind.config.cjs` inside but it seems to be updated whenever the `dev server` triggers a style update. I've tried changing it but it changes back.

When I create a `tailwind.config.js` file in the root folder, it doesn't seem to be used by the project. I've tried:

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
    theme: {
        extend: {
            fontFamily: {
                sans: ['Nunito', ...defaultTheme.fontFamily.sans],
            },
        },
    },
};
```

Instead the browser shows that these fonts are applied by default:

```
font-family: ui-sans-serif, system-ui, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", Arial, "Noto Sans", sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol", "Noto Color Emoji";I
```

Comment: What is your `@font-face` CSS part? For example, as [shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66712645/8816585).

Comment: @kissu I have not set any `font-face` in css. Is this not configurable in the config file?

Comment: Your tailwind config and the CSS file are 2 different things. I'm not sure how you load your fonts but I always did [like that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68166329/8816585), it seems normal to me and works fine.

Answer (score 0):

> When I create a `tailwind.config.js` file in the root folder, it doesn't seem to be used by the project.

Have you specified [`configPath`](https://tailwindcss.nuxt.dev/getting-started/options/#configpath) in nuxt configuration file?

This works for me:

```
export default defineNuxtConfig({
    modules: ["@nuxtjs/tailwindcss"],
    tailwindcss: {
        configPath: "~/tailwind.config.ts",
    },
})
```

Comment: This gives an error "Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'tailwindcss' does not exist in type 'NuxtConfig'"

So It's not even possible to config tailwind on Nuxt 3 using Typescript

Comment: @Vixson, You will get an error if you haven't built the project. Nuxt adds those properties to the config only after you run the project with npm run dev.

Comment: Oh... I see. So it's not actually an error it's just that the Nuxt builds the various modules configs after the first run... lol... I found that out the hard way. Thanks, @Anoromi